# How to convert existing multi module python script to be used in AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, aws-lambda

As directed, I have configured the handler as directed. For e.g. *single_file.lambda_handler*

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    hubspot_api()
    sheet_clear()
    hubspot_properties()
    remaining code
```

But it does the code does not execute and returns time out error. The configured time is apt for the running code. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Try to add print statements inside the handler function and check if those get printed.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda execution timeout mostly means, that Your lambda do not have permission to do what You want. I'll check if external HTTP communication hubspot_api is reachable. Also, I strongly suggest using simple logging or AWS X-Ray with segments that can help to figure out where the problem is.